# 2D DFT in image processing in python

Tags: fft, fourier-transform, python, dft

I try to compute 2D DFT in a greyscale image with this formula:

[image]

I write the code bellow with python

```
def DFT2D(image):
    data = np.asarray(image)
    M, N = image.size # (img x, img y)
    dft2d = np.zeros((M,N))
    for k in range(M):
        for l in range(N):
            sum_matrix = 0.0
            for m in range(M):
                for n in range(N):
                    e = cmath.exp(- 2j * np.pi * ((k * m) / M + (l * n) / N))
                    sum_matrix +=  data[m,n] * e
            dft2d[k,l] = sum_matrix
    return dft2d
```

I think I have some problems because I do not get the expected result. I get the image below:

[image]

I do not know where is the problem in my code!

---

I don't want to use a built-in function, I assume this should be work but maybe it has some mathematical issue. when I get a result matrix and convert it to image it does not as same as expected DFT image

Comment: Why isn't it the expected result?  What are you expecting to see?

Comment: @PeterK. A black picture with the maximum in the center of it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I think it's mostly missing the line

```
    dft2d = np.zeros((M,N),dtype=complex)
```

in your code. Otherwise your sum may not end up being complex.

And then you can't then plot the resulting image... because that needs to be real-valued.

I modified your code so that it sort of works (but is *very* slow). See below.  This results in something more like what you expect --- though because of the indexing, the peak is in the top-left corner rather than the middle.  There's probably something like Matlab's `fftshift` function that will center it for you.

[image]

---

## Updated Code Below

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import PIL
import cmath

def DFT2D(image):
    data = np.asarray(image)
    M, N = image.size # (img x, img y)
    dft2d = np.zeros((M,N),dtype=complex)
    for k in range(M):
        for l in range(N):
            sum_matrix = 0.0
            for m in range(M):
                for n in range(N):
                    e = cmath.exp(- 2j * np.pi * ((k * m) / M + (l * n) / N))
                    sum_matrix +=  data[m,n,1] * e
            dft2d[k,l] = sum_matrix
    return dft2d

img = PIL.Image.open("example.jpg")
img2 = img.resize((50,50))
plt.imshow(img2)
dft = DFT2D(img2)
plt.imshow(dft.real)
```

Comment: yes it worked, I shifted and it gets to the center, Thank you very much. Just one more question, why it gets purple instead of black!?

Comment: @MasoudKhani I suspect it's because the image values can go negative, so the image is  plotted normalized. That brings the "floor" level up a bit from black, to make it a dark purple in the image.

Comment: @Peter K.
I try to use the function 'DFT2D' on a 2D array (or matrix of size M*N) and I got the following error " TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object". For this I've used 'M,N = input()' that still gives the error message? Can you please explain how to overcome this error? Thanks. N.B.: This is not an answer but less scope to comment on this thread

Comment: Hello pluto and welcome to Physics SE. As you have already mentioned, this is not an answer to the original question. This means that you should either wait until you get more reputation to acquire the privilege of posting comments (which I understand that may be a bit frustrating) or post another question. Additionally, I believe that your specific question may be better suited for StackOverflow. I am sure someone here may be able to answer it but you may also want to ask there.

Comment: @pluto As ZaellixA says, please ask another question. StackOverflow is a better place for your specific question because we tend not to answer programming / code debugging questions here.